# Remove data from Firebase but not permanently

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to remove some data from the fire base but not permanently get back this data on the next day.

I am working on android app where a task list created by user and save it on fire base real-time database for some days that user wants and when he completes its task remove it from task list and save the remove task in history activity on date when he completes a task and get back this task list as it he makes on the first day.

Comment: Could you please show us what you have tried so far by sharing the code you written to solve this. Have you had any explicit errors while trying to achieve your goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to maintain a "History" list, just create a new Collection (I've been using Firestore so forgot what the main key-value pair in Firebase database is called) and save your deleted user entries in that collection/base key-value pair.

So, for example, if your database structure looks like this now.

```
-main
    |_user_data
      |_user1
      | |_user1 stuff 
      |_user2
        |_user2 stuff
```

Then make it,

```
-main
    |_user_data
    | |_user1
    | | |_user1 stuff 
    | |_user2
    |   |_user2 stuff
    |
    |_deleted_user_notes
      |_user1 
      | |_user 1 deleted notes
      |_user2 deleted notes
        |_user 2 deleted notes
```

Just move your notes into this sub-collection after delete is pressed on the list. And in Activity where you're fetching the deleted notes, use this `deleted_user_notes` instead of `user_data`.

I'd say check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57208391/10635880) answer, as it's easier to implement than my method.

Comment: You've added image path of your computer here. Upload that image somewhere on internet so that others/me will be able to see

Comment: You can add another one collection like taskS and make it something like "deletedTasks"

Comment: Yeah I mean yours is more simpler and better. @a_local_nobody